# Flutter.io (Dart) - How to count items returned from Firebase query that meet certain conditions

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

In a screen, a Firebase list has logic applied to

1. reactively detect blueness of widgets
2. hide blue widgets
3. show non-blue widgets

I want to count the blue widgets.

What is the best way to do this?

```
return new StreamBuilder<int>(
    stream: subscribeMyThings(thing.id),
    builder: (context, thingsSnapshot) {
        return new FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: getThings(thing.id),
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
            return new ReactiveWidget<int>(
              reactiveRef: getThingBlueness(snapshot.key),
              widgetBuilder: (checkBlueness) {
                // code to check blueness here

                // if Thing is blue, place empty container
                if (thingIsBlue) {
                  return new Container();
                  // *** how do I count these??? ***
                }

                // or, if Thing is NOT blue
                return new Thing(thing.id);
                );
              },
            );
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not hitting the problem from the proper point of view, plus the title is misleading.

You might not intend to count the widget shown on the screen, but rather count a subset of Firebase database entries that fit some conditions.
This makes a big difference in Flutter, since counting widgets involves the the render tree, the layouts and graphics in general, while it looks you want to address a data problem.

If I am right then you might consider having an index in your db keeping track of the number of blue items and listen to it in another streambuilder.

Long story short, you might want to keep a map< id, blueness >, update each element at build time, and iterate over the map whenever required to count.

```
// somewhere in your outer scope
Map<int, bool> _bluenessMap = new Map<int, bool>();

  return new StreamBuilder<int>(
    stream: subscribeMyThings(thing.id),
    builder: (context, thingsSnapshot) {
        return new FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: getThings(thing.id),
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
            return new ReactiveWidget<int>(
              reactiveRef: getThingBlueness(snapshot.key),
              widgetBuilder: (checkBlueness) {
                // code to check blueness here


                // ----------------------------
                // before return let us update the map

                _bluenessMap[thing.id] = thingIsBlue

                // ----------------------------

                // if Thing is blue, place empty container
                if (thingIsBlue) {
                  return new Container();
                }

                // or, if Thing is NOT blue
                return new Thing(thing.id);

                );
              },
            );
        );
      }

  // call me when you want to count
  int fancyBlueCounter(){
      int result = 0;
      for(bool isBlue in _bluenessMap.values){
        if(isBlue) result += 1;
      }
      return result;
  }
```

**Edit**

Since the author of the question confirmed it is a "data problem", I feel like suggesting another (maybe better) way to address it.

**Aggregates** or Indexes are (in my opinion) the proper way to solve your problem. Anytime someone touches a *Thing*  depending on its *blueness* it refreshes a purposefully created aggregate in the DB (actually also a simple data entry *count*). You can do this either following any function editing *Things* with a **transaction** updating the *blue count*, or with **cloud functions** (see doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions)) listening for changes events (creation, deletion, and edit) and updating the *count* as well.

Comment: You are exactly right, I want to count a subset of data that meet some conditions. This looks like it should work beautifully, but I could not get it working. I'll keep trying and if I can get it running correctly I'll mark as answer.

Comment: Edited title and question to better reflect this.

Comment: @Deborah as I mentioned it is difficult to provide a minimal working example with just the code you provided. Anyhow I'll be glad to help if I can, feel free to give some more details concerning the result.

Comment: @Deborah please check also the "data" solution as in the updated answer.

Comment: I agree completely with @fabio-veronese. I came across your exact issue in my flutter app working with Firestore and ended up creating a collection of document ids adjacent to my main collection, i.e. the id of every doc in my main collection is placed in a separate id collection. I just had to put in some overhead in the app to manage/use the id's collection parallel to the primary Firestore stream. Works just fine. I thought Firebase real time database might work better, but I think it will be similar in terms of what you and I are trying to do. Good luck!